# Why is a windows filename reporting it's name with unicode non-characters (&#xFFFF;)?

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, unicode, ntfs

I have encountered a file that reports it's filename as `풜〣&#xFFFF;&#xFFFF;`

This then fails to be interpreted as XML by SQL Server, as it is called out as a specifically invalid character in both XML v1.0 and v1.1.

When I `dir` the directory in `cmd`, I get `????` as the filename, which does seem to be four characters.

How I got any filename out of it at all was by PowerShell's `Get-ChildItem`.

Is there something else going on here? How could a Unicode Non-Character like '' (`&#xFFFF`) get into a filename, or is this somehow related to not installed language packs or something?

Comment: The non-character `U+FFFF` is a legal 'character' in an NTFS filename, though not a good idea. It's probably the result of failed encoding at some point.

Comment: cmd's `dir` command should output the UTF-16 text, but a pipe defaults to encoding to the OEM codepage (e.g CP437), which will replace `U+FFFF` with a question mark. To have cmd use UTF-16 instead, pipe the output from `cmd /U /c dir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @eryksun's comments, I was able to use the `/U` unicode switch in `cmd` to work with filenames with `&#xFFFF`.